# Php session echo not showing anymore?

Tags: php, html, authentication

I have this php that is a login screen then goes to the profile page, and there it is suppose to echo out the users; username and email on the screen. I had it working before haven't changed anything but now only the username prints out.

This is the login php:

```
public function Login($username, $password){

if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)){

    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT username, password, email FROM users WHERE BINARY username = ? AND BINARY password = ?");
    $stmt->bindParam(1,$username);
    $stmt->bindParam(2,$password);
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->rowCount() == 1){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $email = $stmt->fetchColumn(2);
        $email = $_SESSION['email'];
        header('Location: http://www.mywebsite.com/dev/profile.php');
        }else{
            echo "Incorrect username or password please try again.";
        }               
    }else{
        echo "Must type username or password.";
    }       
}
```

This is the profile php :

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    $username = $_SESSION["username"];
    $email = $_SESSION["email"];
    if(!$_SESSION["username"]){
        header("Location: http://www.mywebsitelogin.com/dev/");
}
```

And this is how im echoing it out:

```
<?php echo '<h1>'.htmlentities($username).'</h1>'; ?>
<?php echo '<h3>'.htmlentities($email).'</h3>'; ?>
```

Also on a side question is there a more constant way of including a file inside a php other than include_once(). Because it's happened where that part of the php code fails for no reason when refreshing or entering a page.

Comment: Please add error or log message, debug trace, or anything that make others people easy to understand what is the problem

Comment: Perhaps you should [EDIT](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20319976/edit) the question, especially the title as it is quite unclear what you are asking us of, friend.

Comment: There is no error messages or anything. When the user enters their profile page after login their username and email is suppose to be echoed out in the middle of the page. It used to print out both, now only the username shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not putting the email into the session. You're doing the opposite:

```
$email = $stmt->fetchColumn(2);
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
```

Change that to:

```
$_SESSION['email'] = $stmt->fetchColumn(2);
```

Perhaps it appeared to work before because during debugging, you had already stored the email variable in the session.